# SDL apps doesn't run on other computers

Tags: c++, dependencies, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

**I figured out the problem, I basically just put all the .dll files into my System32 so the application would look for .dlls in there. Then I gave the exe to a friend with missing .dlls. Sorry for this awful question**

I've compiled several SDL applications and none of them run on other computers than the one they are compiled on. I include the .dll files with the .exe and the other computers have visual C++ and what not installed.
[image: Here's an image of the dependency walker]

This is what dependency walker spits out when I tell it to examine my .exe, I can't find anything useful on google with this information. All of the programs work fine on my own computer, and most of them are bare bones. My compiler is set up based on [This tutorial by "Lazy Foo"](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php) I'm only linking -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 and only searching inside of SDL's directories.

If anyone could translate the error messages or help figure out what is going wrong I'd be very grateful, I'm pretty sure the problem is with dependencies somehow.

Comment: I suspect there are missing .dlls. Post all the .dlls you included with the .exe.

Comment: SDL2.dll and SDL2_image.dll, I'm only including those two headers and ctime aside from my own files.

Comment: I tested dependency walker on several game exes and they all showed the exact same error as the one I'm getting; Despite working like a charm. I'm getting more and more confused the more I try to fix this.

Comment: You should post the exact error message you are getting when executing your application on a different machine.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about this, very sorry everyone I just did a silly goof and threw a buch of .dlls into my system32 so I didn't know what made my apps work opposed to other computers. I sorted it out with a friend but I might as well leave this up in case anyone else does the same thing.